# c# Difference between versions in documentation (.Net 7 vs .NET 8) ("diff")

Tags: c#

Microsoft provides different versions of ther documentation for the DotNet Standard.  I'd like to know is there a way to get an automated diff / highlightling on what has changed between the versions?   Or an info that nothing has changed.I'm asking this question more general. I will copy and diff this specific page myself but i'd like to have a button or some info like "no update since .Net 1.1"
Example Page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all in markdown on GitHub.  Hit the "Edit this document" button to jump to the .md in GitHub.

[image]

You can see older versions or switch to "Blame" view on the current doc to see when each current line was last touched.